# Java: Writing string to .txt issue

Tags: java

Here is the longish, but commented code for my program:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   //get path of dump file
   Path directory = Paths.get("E:\\Temp\\");
    try
    {
        Files.createDirectory(directory);
    }
    catch(FileAlreadyExistsException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Directory already exists.");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not create directory.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Path file = directory.resolve("dump.txt");

    //set initial vars and get system properties
    long gig = 1_073_741_824L;
    String separator = System.lineSeparator();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
    Iterable<FileStore> fstores = fs.getFileStores();

    //write data to file
    try(WritableByteChannel wbc = Files.newByteChannel(file, CREATE, WRITE,TRUNCATE_EXISTING))
    {
        //write heading to file
        ByteBuffer buf_1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(new String("*****FILE SYSTEM DATA*****" + separator + separator).getBytes());
        wbc.write(buf_1);

        //write file store information to file
        for(FileStore store : fstores)
        {
            //set up empty string and formatter for it
            String f_string = "";
            Formatter f = new Formatter(f_string);
            //fill f_string
            f.format("\nStore: %-20s Format: %-5s Capacity: %5dGB Unallocated: %5dGB",
                    store.name(), 
                    store.type(), 
                    store.getTotalSpace()/gig, 
                    store.getUnallocatedSpace()/gig);
            //test
            System.out.println(f_string);
            //set up buffers
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(f_string.getBytes());
            //write to file
            wbc.write(buf);     
            f.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The purpose of this program is to create a .txt file called "dump.txt" at a (currently) hard-coded location on my system containing information about my file system. The problem that I am having is that nothing is written to the file other than the title "*****FILE SYSTEM DATA*****", and in fact when I debug the code, every line between creating the Formatter and the final catch block does not get stepped through. The way in which I attempt to write this data to the file is the same as how I write buf_1 (heading) to the file, and so I am completely at a loss as to why this problem is occurring.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have thought about using a Writer instead, but for the sake of my own knowledge I am using channel/buffer objects instead. However, if you know some particular reason why a Writer would be superior, please let me know :).

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the formatted string to `f_string` before writing it to the file.

Instead of

```
String f_string = "";
Formatter f = new Formatter(f_string);
f.format("\nStore: %-20s Format: %-5s Capacity: %5dGB Unallocated: %5dGB",
         store.name(), 
         store.type(), 
         store.getTotalSpace()/gig, 
         store.getUnallocatedSpace()/gig);;
```

You should have something like:

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(f_string);
String f_string =  
    f.format("\nStore: %-20s Format: %-5s Capacity: %5dGB Unallocated: %5dGB",
             store.name(), 
             store.type(), 
             store.getTotalSpace()/gig, 
             store.getUnallocatedSpace()/gig);;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work. I believe the reason is that Formatter.format() returns a Formatter, not whatever type it was that implements Appendable that you passed to the Formatter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

[`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) does not work like you think it does, but you don't actually need to use it anyway. Use `String.format` instead:

```
        String f_string = String.format("\nStore: %-20s Format: %-5s Capacity: %5dGB Unallocated: %5dGB",
                store.name(), 
                store.type(), 
                store.getTotalSpace()/gig, 
                store.getUnallocatedSpace()/gig);
```

Comment: Thank you - that changed worked. I was using a Formatter because I was initially trying to use a CharBuffer as a view buffer, and thus was formatting the input to that buffer (but that method led to each character being double-spaced for some odd reason). Thanks for reminding me about this string method!